# Is it possible to use MacPorts with ONLY Xcode 4.3 CLI tools installed?

Tags: xcode, macports

I understand that starting with Xcode 4.3 the CLI tools are a separate installation and that caused many issues with existing MacPorts installations upon upgrade.  This question is not about that problem.  With a brand new rMBP 15.4", I attempted to install *only* the CLI tools via download from the Apple Developer site.  Not only did MacPorts fail to find Xcode, but xcodebuilder itself failed to execute (simply hangs...).  I tried many iterations of using xcode-select to point to the CLI binaries, but I couldn't get either MacPorts or just the CLI binaries to work.

Is it simply not possible to only install (the wonderfully tidy and SSD-friendly) CLI tools and get MacPorts to work?  I was not able to find anybody that specifically confirmed or denied this in several searches here and on Google in general.  With a 128GB SSD, every GB counts... and the 4+GB Xcode install (99% of which I don't need) is a waste of space.  Is there something in the proper Xcode install that MacPorts requires?

Comment: I would suggest that you first install Xcode, then the command line tools and then finally just delete the Xcode stuff (Xcode app, utilities, documentation, etc).

Comment: @PaulR, that is a suggestion and I thank you for the quick response, but it seems a bit messy as parts of the OS may still expect Xcode to be installed.  Also, it seems the CLI binaries are inside the Xcode.app bundle with the full install, so one would really have to be careful what one deletes, correct?

Comment: Yes, you'd need to drill down into `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents` and use a little common sense as to what to delete.